# Can I setup a local transparent proxy to forward requests to another another web proxy

Tags: iptables, proxy, squid, http-proxy

I would like to set up a local Linux system to tunnel all http/https requests transparently through a corporate proxy. Many scripts honor http_proxy environment variables but some don't and it is a big hassle.

Is there a way to setup squid or something similar to forward all outgoing http requests through the corporate proxy? It should just forward the requests, I don't need to look into SSL traffic.

Answer (score 1):

Transparently proxying http traffic on port 80 is relatively simple - set up squid, and use iptables rules to direct all port 80 traffic to it.  Works for other ports too.

Transproxying encrypted https traffic is far more difficult.  Impossible unless you performn a man-in-the-middle attack on the traffic and the certificate chain.  You might want to look: [Transparent SSL proxy myths and facts](https://serverfault.com/questions/280796/transparent-ssl-proxy-myths-and-facts).